# How to create new base line / reset in EF code first?

Tags: entity-framework

So when prototyping an application using Entity Framework code first, I ended up with a lot of migrations.

I'm not interested in keeping all the classes that were generated, I want to say: ok, this is my base line for v1.

How can I reset EF Code first?

Comment: Just delete everything from the model except the entities (+ associations) you want to hang on to and regenerate/reinitialize the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the first migration in your database you needs just:

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration:"YourFirstMigrationName"
```

in your parkage manage console.

But it just return the version of your database, not your code first POCO classes. For control the version you need another tool, like the Team foundation or git.